# cannot load R package 'tm.plugin.webmining'

Tags: r

I'm using x64 windows 7 and R i386 3.1.1

I installed 'tm.plugin.webmining' package. but when I load this package using

```
library(tm.plugin.webming)
```

flowing error occure:

```
Error : .onLoad is failed at loadNamespace() because of 'rJava':
Call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
Error: Cannot load 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
LoadLibrary failure: Cannot find the module.
```

I already installed latest jvm. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the `Java_Home` path on R
`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="path/java/home")`

ie

`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin")`

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem. if JDK is installed in the system, I need to install JRE additionally.